# programmatically turning off a camera

Tags: gazebo-9

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Hello,

To make a video recording of my gazebo stage I have followed tutorial at http://gazebosim.org/tutorials?tut=camera_save&cat=sensors and successfully recorded jpg files for the screen.

How can I turn off this camera programmatically?

Best regards,
C.A.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/25004/programmatically-turning-off-a-camera/) by [altineller](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/23788/altineller/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 9 on 2020-05-02

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

You can get the sensor and deactivate it:

```
#include <gazebo/sensors/SensorManager.hh>
sensors::SensorPtr sensor = sensors::SensorManager::Instance()->GetSensor(
    "world_name::model_name::link_name::sensor_name");
sensor->SetActive(false);
```

If you are not sure about the name, you can get the names of all sensors and identify yours:

```
for (sensors::SensorPtr sensor : sensors::SensorManager::Instance()->GetSensors())
    gzmsg << sensor->ScopedName() << "\n";
```

At the same time, you can skip the whole saving images thing, and directly record a video with the camera:

```
sensors::CameraSensorPtr camera_sensor =
  std::static_pointer_cast<sensors::CameraSensor>(sensor);
camera_sensor->Camera()->StartVideo("mp4");
camera_sensor->Camera()->StopVideo();
camera_sensor->Camera()->SaveVideo("~/recording");
```

---

Originally posted by [nlamprian](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/8391/nlamprian/) with karma: 833 on 2020-05-02

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [altineller](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/23788/altineller/) on 2020-05-02**:
thank you for the answer. is there any example code that I can work on? I have a setup where I run a simulation for 100seconds, then stop recording at that time. unfortunately, killing gazebo with a timer node, does work, but it takes a varying amount of time to stop, which records more images.

**Comment by [nlamprian](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/8391/nlamprian/) on 2020-05-02**:
You can create a world plugin and configure things as you like in there. If you don't wanna get into that, I recently released a plugin that records videos, which you can control through ROS services. See [gazebo_video_monitor_plugins](https://github.com/nlamprian/gazebo_video_monitor_plugins)

**Comment by [rezenders](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/26928/rezenders/) on 2020-06-16**:
When I use `sensor->SetActive(false);`  I have to call it several times before the change takes effect, should it be like this?